# Windows 7 workstation can't get Active Directory 2003 printers

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory, windows-7, shared-printers

Server : Windows 2003 Small Business (no SP)
Workstation : Windows 7 Pro

With a fresh Windows 7 Pro installation, I've been able to join our
existing 2003-server domain, and I get access to the server's shared
files, but when I try to install our network printers, the "add printer"
procedure doesn't include Active Directory printers.

Also, using the "active directory" search in the "network" window,
always give empty search results (printers, users, nothing!).

The existing XP workstations do that flawlessly.

Why does Windows 7 seems unable to look into the Directory ? What
should I do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It tells me that no driver has been found on the network

That sounds like the server doesn't have drivers for your platform. For example, if your Windows 7 is 64-bit, and the server only has 32-bit drivers, you'll get this kind of thing.

Comment: Ouch ! Didn't think of that ! Yes, W7 is 64bit (first time I install a 64bit OS) and W2003 is 32bit. Could it be the root of the Active Directory problem too ?

Comment: If you haven't had the Server 2008 schema enhancements installed to your tree/domain, its possible. Though I still suspect using a client OS two full revs newer than the server expects is the more likely cause.

Comment: I've read something about adding the 2008 schema enhancements to 2003, I'll try that someday. Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess as I'm not sure how this affects finding objects in the directory, but have you turned on Network Discovery on the Win7 workstation?

Comment: Yes, I did turn 'Network Discovery' on, but it didn't solve my problem. Maybe I should add that, most of the time, the other computers in the network, including server, are well listed in the 'computer' panel.

Answer (score 0):

Can you browse to your print server like `\\printservername` and add them that way? Do you see them at all when you browse to the print server?

Comment: Yes, I can see the printers listed when I browse to \\server, but when I right-click on any and choose "connect..." it tells me that no driver has been found on the network (is this how I'm supposed to install a net printer from there?).

Answer (score 0):

The resolution for this would be to install the 64bit drivers on the server! you should be able to do this via the printer properties and sharing tab > look at the bottom for additional drivers.
You may be needed to supply the 64bit NTPrint processor if you need this I've got a copy of both the 32bit and 64bit NTPrint directories which I can send you if required!